# Trying to find an entity in the database

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

I have a code like this:

```
AJPAController aJPAController;
AClass aClass = aJPAController.find((Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")));

try{
    if(aJpaController.contains(aClass)){
       response.sendRedirect("gosomewhere.com");
     }
}
catch (java.lang.NullPointerException R){
     response.sendRedirect("gosomewhereelse.com");
}
```

I am trying to find an entity in database, if the entity is in the database then it will perform an action, if it does not it will perform another action.

I might have a logical mistake in trying first find and then contains method.. but I don't know.

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT:
Sorry for the late reply. I had to deal with an urgent matter. Full error stack trace is:

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the web application. Please review the following stack trace for more information regarding the error.

Exception Details: java.lang.NullPointerException
  null

Possible Source of Error:
   Class Name: org.apache.jsp.user.report_005fredirect_jsp
   File Name: report_005fredirect_jsp.java from
   Method Name: _jspService
   Line Number: 74

Source not available. Information regarding the location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

org.apache.jsp.user.report_005fredirect_jsp._jspService(report_005fredirect_jsp.java from :74)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:109)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:408)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:483)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:373)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
com.labristeknoloji.lcas.client.filters.SingleSignOutNameAddFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutNameAddFilter.java:56)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
org.jasig.cas.client.util.AssertionThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(AssertionThreadLocalFilter.java:40)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.doFilter(HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.java:50)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:167)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
com.labristeknoloji.lcas.client.filters.LCASAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(LCASAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:104)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
com.labristeknoloji.lrms.web.filter.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:76)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:229)
org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:334)
org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:814)
org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:743)
org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:936)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:682)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: What does AJPAController do? What does its find() method return?

Comment: I've never caught NullPointerException in my life. Re-write you code so you don't need to: `if (response == null) ...` etc

Comment: AJPA Controller initializes Entity Manager and finds/updates/persists entity instances.
Find method returns an object of type AClass.

Comment: actually my aim is not catching NullPointerException. I am trying to find an entity instance in the persistence context. I am trying to figure out how to handle this entity's nonexistence state. Do you have any opinion about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the [EntityManager.find(...)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29) method.

It will return `null` if the entity does not exist in database. So it's up to the implementation of the `AJPAController.find(...)` method what it is doing with that information. (Just for clarification: As I understood, `AJPAController` is a wrapper around an `EntityManager`.)

Comment: sorry for the late reply.. I already checked that method. Because it returns null, java throws null pointer exception. I try to handle this state with try catch, but still no solution...

Comment: There was a problem with the logical order of my code. When I corrected the order and use .find method it worked. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must add to this post "AJPAController" code an full error stacktrace. Without this, we can't help you.
Maybe Integer.parseInt, or request.getParameter return nullpointerexception?